# Making java output a specific number of characters, depending on the input in the console

Tags: java

I need to write a program that let's the user write 3 words in the console, then the program reprints those 3 words (one in each line) but also fills out the remaining spaces in each line with dots (".") so the total number of characters in each lines becomes a total of 30 characters.

Example:

Input:

```
Hello 
Me 
Overflow
```

Output:

```
.........................Hello
............................Me
......................Overflow
```

This is the code that I currently have which generates an error. I have been given the code (at the bottom) as part of my assignment and need to write the `repeatChar` method to make it work.

The first thing I did was to add the following commands in the code, in order to save the 3 words into the array `threeWord`.

```
threeWord[1] = wordOne;
threeWord[2] = wordTwo;
threeWord[3] = wordThree;
```

Next, I had to write the method `repeatChar`, and I decided to use a for-loop to make it repeat dots for each individual line, but I'm having a hard time making it fit with the rest of the code. Any guidance would be much appreciated, thanks.

```
import java.util.*;

public class FillDots {
    private static int LineLength = 30;
    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        String[] threeWord = new String [3]; // Defines 3 locations to place strings in the array "threeWord"
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Type in three words:");
        String wordOne = console.next();
        threeWord[1] = wordOne; // Saves first word to array "threeWord"
        String wordTwo = console.next();
        threeWord[2] = wordTwo; // Saves second word to array "threeWord"
        String wordThree = console.next();
        threeWord[3] = wordThree; // Saves third word to array "threeWord"
        for(int i = 0; i < threeWord.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(repeatChar('.', LineLength - threeWord[i].length()) + threeWord[i]);
        }
    }
    public static String repeatChar(String LineLength) {
        for(int j = 0; j < LineLength; j++) {
            System.out.print(".");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Array indices start at 0 `threeWord[0], threeWord[1], threeWord[2]`

Comment: @user7 Good catch, thanks! :)

Comment: If you just had the repeat method build a string of periods, that would work. However, you're calling a method that prints out with no String return in another System::println;

Comment: When you ask a question in the future, please be sure to include any errors that you get from your code and indicate which lines cause the errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides the index starts from `0`, you need return the dots in the `repeatChar` method:

```
public static String repeatChar(char repeatChar, int repeatTimes) {
    String result = "";
    for(int j = 0; j < repeatTimes; j++) {
        result += repeatChar;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there any way that I can keep the code for the loop (with the variable i) as it is, and make changes to the `repeatChar` method? I'm having a hard time understanding the `'.',` part of the method in the loop. I'm guessing I shouldn't be printing "." in my `repeatChar` method?

Comment: That works perfectly! Thank you. Is the command `String result = "";` basically telling Java to start with "zero dots", and then the `result += repeatChar;` basically adds one dot character every time it is needed? And how does Java know the length of `repeatTime` (basically how does it know how many iterations to do in the loop)?

Comment: You pass `repeatTimes` to it and use `repeatTimes` in the `for` loop. That's how it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use existing library for doing padding

```
for(String temp:threeWord) 
  system.out.println(org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.leftPad(temp, 10, ".") );
```

this might simplify your code